# How to count method calls, but not attribute access?

Tags: python, inheritance, metaprogramming

I'm preparing a parent class for multiple classes and from its perspective I need to be aware if a particular instance method was called or not.

I started working on something like this:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
class ParentClass:
    def __init__(self, ):
        self.call_count = defaultdict(int)

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        if item != 'call_count':
            self.call_count[item] += 1
        return object.__getattribute__(self, item)


class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def child_method(self):
        pass
```

Unfortunately, the `call_count` also includes accessing of the field, without calling it:

```py
ob = ChildClass()

ob.child_method()
ob.child_method

assert ob.call_count['child_method'] == 1  # it's 2
```

How can I, from object instance detect that its field is being called (not only accessed)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (python3) solution using a custom metaclass:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from functools import wraps
import inspect

def count_calls(func):
    name = func.__name__

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # creates the instance counter if necessary
        counter = getattr(self, "_calls_counter", None)
        if counter is None:
            counter = self._calls_counter = defaultdict(int)
        counter[name] += 1
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

    wrapper._is_count_call_wrapper = True
    return wrapper


class CallCounterType(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        for name, attr in attrs.items():
            if not inspect.isfunction(attr):
                # this will weed out any callable that is not truly a function
                # (including nested classes, classmethods and staticmethods)
                continue

            try:
                argspec = inspect.getargspec(attr)
            except TypeError:
                # "unsupported callable" - can't think of any callable
                # that might have made it's way until this point and not
                # be supported by getargspec but well...
                continue

            if not argspec.args:
                # no argument so it can't be an instancemethod
                # (to be exact: a function designed to be used as instancemethod)
                # Here again I wonder which function could be found here that
                # doesn't take at least `self` but anyway...
                continue

            if getattr(attr, "_is_count_call_wrapper", False):
                # not sure why we would have an already wrapped func here but etc...
                continue

            # ok, it's a proper function, it takes at least one positional arg,
            # and it's not already been wrapped, we should be safe
            attrs[name] = count_calls(attr)

        return super(CallCounterType, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)


class ParentClass(metaclass=CallCounterType):
    pass

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def child_method(self):
        pass
```

Note that storing call counts on the instance only allow to count instancemethods calls, obviously...

Comment: Looks awesome, well documented, and works. The following prints `1`: `ob = ChildClass(); ob.child_method(); ob.child_method; print(ob._calls_counter['child_method']);`. Also works with multiple objects, so nothing stored at class level. Only thing to change might be to make `_calls_counter` public?

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen depends on the intended use mostly. As far as I understand this is part of a framework and is actually part of the framework implementation so I'd rather keep it protected (or even truly private to avoid name conflicts) - but we don't really have enough context to tell.

Comment: Sure, I get it. I was thinking in terms of reflecting the test code provided by the asker. But you're right, we don't have enough information to really know what's right.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a little "dirty", but wrapping all methods with a counting function could cover what you need:

```
from collections import defaultdict
class ParentClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.call_count = defaultdict(int)

        for attr in dir(self):
            if not attr.startswith('__') and attr != '_wrapper_factory':
                callback = getattr(self, attr)
                if hasattr(callback, '__call__'):
                    setattr(self, attr, self._wrapper_factory(callback))

    def _wrapper_factory(self, callback):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            self.call_count[callback.__name__] += 1
            callback(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

class ChildClass(ParentClass):
    def child_method(self):
        pass


ob = ChildClass()

ob.child_method()
ob.child_method

assert ob.call_count['child_method'] == 1
```

Should give no assertion errors.

Comment: Thanks, that works just fine. Just two notes:  `fn` --> `callback` typo; also it's a good idea to decorate `def wrapper` with `@wraps(callback)`, to make it appear less dirty :)

The only issue is that now, the `ChildClass.__init__` must call `super()` to make this work... I wonder if there's a way to avoid this drawback

Comment: @Mirek a child class should (almost) always call it's parent's initializer anyway. But putting this code in the initializer is very inefficient, it would be better to wrap the methods at the class level (so you only wrap them once), which can be done with either a class decorator or a custom metaclass.

Comment: @andré : `defaultdict(lambda : 0)` can be expressed more simply as `defaultdict(int)`. Classes _are_ callable...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Thanks. I just copied the original solution of Mirek, but I'll update.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers That sounds interesting. Could you provide an answer with how you would go about doing it at class level. I'm not sure how that would work when you have a reference to `self.call_count` which is at object level. Maybe a `call_count` object method?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yes, it should call it. However, I'm developing a framework for other developers to use, so I think that all meta-programming tricks must be protected from those developers who won't call super(), either as a hack or just a mistake. Anyway I will also be glad to see your class decorator/metaclass solution.

Comment: @AndréC.Andersen `self` is just an ordinary function argument, so the wrapper gets it too (as the first positional argument).

Comment: @Mirek just clearly document that subclasses must call the initializer and that's enough. Trying to "protect" anything against incompetent developpers is a complete waste of everyone's time, it doesn't work even with "B&D" languages like Ada or Java so with something as dynamic as Python it's nothing but a lost battle.

Comment: @Mirek example with metaclass added (and it takes care of creating the counter for you <g>).